# How to make Bokeh select menu update by cluster label

Tags: python, widget, data-visualization, bokeh

I've been doing some research on how to use the Bokeh select widget to update a visualization of a scatterplot I'm working on. I want to be able to select a cluster label from a menu and then points belonging to that cluster will become colored while all other points are gray. I think I'm really close but for whatever reason my graph won't update. Can someone please help? Hope you have a nice day :)

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import output_file, show, output_notebook, save
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Select, DateRangeSlider
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import CustomJS 
from bokeh.layouts import row,column
import random

#generate random points and cluster labels for data
x = [random.randint(0,50) for i in range(200)]
y = [random.randint(0,50) for i in range(200)]
rand_clusters = [random.randint(0,30) for i in range(200)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'x_coord':x, 'y_coord':y,'cluster labels':rand_clusters})

clusters = [str(i) for i in range(len(df['cluster labels'].unique()))]

cols1 = df[['cluster labels','x_coord', 'y_coord']]
cols2 = cols1[cols1['cluster labels'] == '0']

Overall = ColumnDataSource(data=cols1)
Curr = ColumnDataSource(data=cols2)


callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=Overall, sc=Curr), code="""
var f = cb_obj.value
sc.data['x_coord']=[]
sc.data['y_coord']=[]
for(var i = 0; i <= source.get_length(); i++){
    if (source.data['cluster labels'][i] == f){
        sc.data['x_coord'].push(source.data['x_coord'][i])
        sc.data['y_coord'].push(source.data['x_coord'][i])
    }
}   
   
sc.change.emit();
""")

menu = Select(options=clusters, value='0', title = 'Cluster #')  

bokeh_p=figure(x_axis_label ='X Coord', y_axis_label = 'Y Coord', y_axis_type="linear",x_axis_type="linear") #creating figure object 
bokeh_p.circle(x='x_coord', y='y_coord', color='green', source=Curr) # plotting the data using glyph circle

menu.js_on_change('value', callback)
layout=column(menu, bokeh_p) 
show(layout)
```

Edit: I have found the issue and I am pulling my hair out on how I missed it: it's a simple datatype mismatch between `rand_clusters` in the DF (which are ints) and `cluster labels` from clusters (which are strings). Since the JS compares the two in order to update `Curr`, there was never a 'True' condition. Simply replace with `rand_clusters = [str(random.randint(0,30)) for i in range(200)]`. Marking this as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue and I am pulling my hair out on how I missed it: it's a simple datatype mismatch between rand_clusters in the DF (which are ints) and cluster labels from clusters (which are strings). Since the JS compares the two in order to update Curr, there was never a 'True' condition. Simply replace with rand_clusters = [str(random.randint(0,30)) for i in range(200)]. Marking this as solved.